# How come you can buy VUSA.L outside of American trading hours?

Tags: etf, nyse, london-stock-exchange

I buy [VUSA.L](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-s-and-p-500-ucits-etf-usd-distributing/overview). One thing that confuses me is that I can buy VUSA when the London Stock Exchange opens. However, when the exchange opens in London, New York is still closed.

So if VUSA tracks the S&P 500, where is its price coming from in the morning London hours during which New York is still closed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is an ETF, which is tracking foreign equities, ticking in my local time zone?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102419/why-is-an-etf-which-is-tracking-foreign-equities-ticking-in-my-local-time-zone)